# Realm usage for non-ui thread

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

I have made use of realm in the non-Ui and ui threads.

Different thread jobs are queued, ui thread jobs are managed from activity or fragments onCreate-onDestroy and using RealmManager.

Always given this error:

> Exception! message:This Realm instance has already been closed, making
>   it unusable.

Please help me!

> Ui thread operations controller:

RealmManager:

```
public class RealmManager {

    private static String TAG = RealmManager.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final ThreadLocal<Realm> localRealms = new ThreadLocal<>();

    private static Monarchy monarchy;
    private static Monarchy.Builder monarchyBuilder;

    public static Monarchy getMonarchy() {

        checkDefaultConfiguration();

        if (monarchy == null) {

            monarchy = new Monarchy.Builder()
                    .setRealmConfiguration(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration())
                    .build();
        }
        return monarchy;
    }

    public static Monarchy.Builder getMonarchyBuilder() {

        checkDefaultConfiguration();

        if (monarchyBuilder == null) {
            monarchyBuilder = new Monarchy.Builder();
        }
        return monarchyBuilder;
    }

    public static Realm open() {

        checkDefaultConfiguration();

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        if (checkRealm(realm)) {
            localRealms.set(realm);
        }

        Mylog.i(TAG, " open Realm.getDefaultInstance() realm:" + realm + localRealms);

        return realm;
    }

    public static Realm getLocalInstance() {

        checkDefaultConfiguration();

        Realm realm = localRealms.get();

        Mylog.i(TAG, " getLocalInstance localRealms.get() realm:" + realm);

        if (!checkRealm(realm)) {
            return open();
        }
        return realm;
    }

    public static void close() {

        Realm realm = localRealms.get();
        Mylog.i(TAG, " close localRealms.get realm:" + realm);
        close(realm);
    }

    public static void close(Realm realm) {

        Mylog.i(TAG, " close realm:" + realm);
        checkDefaultConfiguration();

        if (!checkRealm(realm)) {
            return;
        }

        realm.close();
        controlLocalInstanceCount();
    }

    public static void checkDefaultConfiguration() {

        if (Realm.getDefaultConfiguration() == null) {
            new RealmEncryptionHelper().setDefaultConfiguration();
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkRealm(Realm realm) {
        return realm != null && !realm.isClosed();
    }

    private static void controlLocalInstanceCount() {

        // noinspection ConstantConditions
        Mylog.i(TAG, " controlLocalInstanceCount:" + Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()));

        // noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()) <= 0) {
            localRealms.set(null);
        }
    }

}
```

> Activity usage on main:

```
onCreate(){
realm = RealmManager.open();
}

onDestroy(){
RealmManager.close(realm);
}
```

> Another thread usage:

```
RealmRunnable realmRunnable = new RealmRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Realm mRealm = getRealm();
                //realm operations for non-ui thread
            }
        };

        getRealmController().addRealmRunnable(realmRunnable);
```

Comment: I... don't see why this has to be so complicated.

Comment: thank you, I am very happy if you share example codes Hed and Epic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<RealmRunnable> runnableConcurrentLinkedQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
>     private Thread realmThread;
>
>             realmThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
>
>                 Realm realm;
>
>                 @Override
>                 public void run() {
>
>                     while (!realmThread.isInterrupted()) {
>
>                         if (runnableConcurrentLinkedQueue.isEmpty()) {
>
>                             synchronized (realmThreadLock) {
>
>                                 if (runnableConcurrentLinkedQueue.isEmpty()) {
> ```

Everything related to the management of serialized runnable execution can be done with one line:

```
Executor singleThreadedExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadedPool();
```

However this would assume that whenever you post a runnable, you need to open/close Realm.

```
singleThreadedExecutor.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            realmManager.openLocalInstance();
            // do whatever
        } finally {
            realmManager.closeLocalInstance();
        }
    }
});
```

With Realm out of the box, this would of course also work:

```
singleThreadedExecutor.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            // do whatever, but you have to pass Realm around instead of `getLocalInstance()`
        }
        // realm is closed here
    }
});
```

If you want the automatic lifecycle management per runnable so that Realm is open with `realmManager.getLocalInstance()` on the background thread WITHOUT manually opening it yourself, then you need to go much deeper. Note that I'm writing it for the very first time here, so it's kinda theoretical in that regard.

Anyways, you'd need to extend `ThreadPoolExecutor` and define `protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r)` and `protected void after(Thread t, Runnable r)`. It would look something like this:

```
 public class RealmThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
     private final RealmManager realmManager;

     public RealmThreadPoolExecutor(RealmManager realmManager) {
          super(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()); // from newSingleThreadedPool
          this.realmManager = realmManager;
     }

     @Override protected void beforeExecute(Thread thread, Runnable runnable) {
         super.beforeExecute(thread, runnable);
         realmManager.openLocalInstance();
         realmManager.getLocalInstance().refresh();
     }

     @Override protected void afterExecute(Thread thread, Runnable runnable) {
         super.afterExecute(thread, runnable);
         realmManager.closeLocalInstance();
     }
}
```

Then instead of your personally managed runnable execution, you'd do:

```
private final Executor realmExecutor = new RealmThreadPoolExecutor(realmManager);

public void addRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
    realmExecutor.execute(runnable);
}
```

and it should be equivalent with what you did. Except instead of `RealmRunnable` and `setRealm`, you'd be calling `realmManager.getLocalInstance()`.

BTW, `get` shouldn't open a Realm, if you need to open a Realm in there then that means the lifecycle management is wrong and you should have opened it previously, so it just hides bug.

---

Technically you *also* chose to use Monarchy instead of using your own manual thread-local cache (though personally I'm not sure if you need both at once...), which means you would be using Realm in a "singleton manner" just by executing your logic inside a `monarchy.doWithRealm(new RealmBlock() {`.

```
@Override public void run() {
    monarchy.doWithRealm((realm) -> {
        // realm is open here
    });
    // realm is closed here
}
```

Monarchy doesn't expose a `open/close` directly because people *never close the Realm* (I've been here for a while now, I know) so this block disallows them from doing so. Unless they manually call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` somewhere, Monarchy will keep Realm closed when it's not needed. The *benefit* here is that if you want a transaction, you do:

```
monarchy.runTransactionSync((realm) -> {
    // do transaction. Realm is opened by config automatically.
});
// realm is closed here.
```

And most importantly, via Monarchy, the UI thread queries are all exposed via a LiveData, where having at least 1 subscriber opens the Realm, while having 0 subscribers closes the Realm -- therefore on UI thread, the Realm lifecycle is managed automatically by your subscriptions to Realm queries. If there are no observers, then Realm is closed.

```
LiveData<List<RealmDog>> dogs;
Observer<List<RealmDog>> observer = dogs -> {
    adapter.updateData(dogs);
};

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    ...
    dogs = monarchy.findAllCopiedWithChanges(realm -> realm.where(RealmDog.class));
    dogs.observeForever(observer);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    dogs.removeObserver(observer);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Regardless of which path you choose, you should probably just delete that `RealmController`, you don't need it.

Comment: I specifically did not have a `RealmRunnable` in this piece of code. I also don't know what lists you have that are null.

Comment: Very very thank you . You saved my life !!
 I didn't downvote. I gave upvote